# iPhone - UITableViewCellAccessoryType

Tags: iphone, uitableview

**Hey Folks**

The following method is called on load, and what it does is that it makes accesoryType for all the cells as CheckMark.

- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewaccessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 
{
return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark; 
}

I want to write an IBAction that does something exactly the same but on a click of a button and not on load. Please help!

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the accessory type of cells when a button is pressed, you'll have to reload the affected rows. Create an instance variable in your table view controller class to hold the active accessory type, and check for it in your -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    // ...

    [cell setAccessoryType:[self cellAccessoryType]];
    return cell;
}
```

Then, set your button's "touch up inside" action to something like this:

```
- (IBAction)changeAccessories:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UITableViewCellAccessoryType accessoryType;

    if (/*condition*/) {
        accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeCheckmark;
    } else {
        accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryTypeNone;
    }

    [self setCellAccessoryType:accessoryType];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

Calling `-reloadData` is a pretty simplistic way of doing things, though. For a smoother solution, check out [-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a).